# Header from bootstrap with HTML contents

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a webpage, I want to be able to do a header for each page 
I want it to consist of

```
(An Image)   Home      news      about us      web      call        email
```

I have this code so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
     <img src="jazz.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" width="250" height="100">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">news</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">about us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">web</a>
        </li>
<li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">call</a>
        </li>
<li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">email</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

However, I just get the image and the rest are under the image, how can I put them all next to each other and make the header background gray? Is there anyway to solve this issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Web</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Call</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">

  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

So this code will give you the header you are looking for. You can add an image in the header if you want still, but you will have to play around with the styling to make it look good. Let me know if you have any questions or need anything clarified. Hope this helps!

Comment: And how do I lower the text a little so its the same level as the image

Comment: Are you including the image in the header? Like where 'WebSiteName' is?

Comment: On the line:    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">    Add in-line style: <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin-top: 50px">  You can play around with the amount of margin you want.

Comment: Actually I fixed it but the color of the background did happen for the image as well, is this not possible?

Comment: Hey I was wondering how could I make it responsive to my browser, for example if I'm on my phone the menu bar stays straight?

Answer (score 0):

You can use display for this. `display:inline` or a newer version `display:flex`

Comment: Show me what you did

Answer (score 0):

Just add some css styling to your HTML to achieve your goal.

Play around with this JSfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ry3hgrtq/

I added these classes to your html.

```
.navbar img {
  display:inline;
  float: left;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```